Ubuntu v22 (vs.) v24 Raid Perc H310 controller / on Dell power edge R420 server
So i have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell power edge R420 server, (with Raid controller Perc H310), and the install works great. it finds the Raid drives, and installs works great.
so i then wanted to install Ubuntu 24.04 on same unit, but it does not find the Raid / drives. (error: wont install / Drives not found)
so then i went back to 22. and then did a OS / upgrade to v24. it all installed fine, it rebooted. and got an error.: (initramfs / busybox error.)
then i had another Server, exactly the same, Poweredge R420, and everything iv done was exact. and does the same thing. Fails.
i did some research, on making changes to BIOS, and re-making the RAID. and formating the drives, nothing seems to work.
So my guess is that... From v22.04 to v24.04 there must be a RAID driver that was changed in the OS, so when the os is updated / or installed, it uses a different driver, and then cant activate the RAID drives.  so... any ideas? / Do i need to install a different RAID card, from a different Manufacture. something that v24 supports. maybe an Intel card. or something.
What about Ubuntu 24.04.1 / does that contain different Raid drivers.  any ideas?

So... an update... I may have figured out something... that maybe a similar / common issue... did some more digging, and found few other posts, that v24 may have some bugs...  or something... so on this issue is. i had 3 HDD, in raid 5. and (v22) had no issue, but (v24 did) so what i did... is disabled / removed 1 drive from the raid setup.  (=2 drives now) and found ubuntu v24 installed just fine, and working.  really weird. so maybe this will help someone.  (maybe at some point, i may try having 4 HDD, and see if what happens on v22 vs v24.)
